# "Right now", it is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you. - correct?

Tags: meaning, usage

**Example 1**

> A: Why are you going to sit here? Didn't you say this place is a bit cold?

> B: **Right now**, it is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you.

**Example 2**

> A: Why are you going to sit here? Didn't you say this place is a bit cold?

> B: It is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you **right now**.

Are both of them correct?

Are they different in meaning?

Comment: Putting _right now_ at the beginning simply emphasises it (that is how the speaker feels at this precise moment).

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are grammatically correct to me as an American (other than I'd use a contraction *it's* for *it is*, but that is purely a style thing). Example 1 strikes me as more natural, since it focuses on addressing why ("right now [the temperature is fine]") B doesn't seem to mind the location.

The tone of voice for "right now" conveys more about subtle differences in meaning, like if B actually does feel a little cold but really enjoys A's company, or if it's acknowledging that while A is generally right, it isn't so bad at the moment. In written text, it's hard to discern.

Answer (score 0):

In many contexts, a fronted adverbial (moving an adverbial phrase such as '*right now*' from the end of a sentence to the beginning) has little or no effect on the meaning at all. However, there is a difference between your two examples that could be perceived by a native speaker:

> It is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you right now.

This is the most idiomatic of the two. Tagging 'right now' on to the end of the sentence is something of a redundancy, as you've already said to the person you're sitting next to "it is relaxing to sit *here*", so it's clear you're talking about the present, but it's a nice thing to add as it conveys you're enjoying the moment.

> Right now, it is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you.

Placing 'right now' at the beginning of the sentence places undue emphasis on it. It sounds like you're stressing that it's only relaxing to sit there at this moment in a way that could suggest it isn't normally relaxing.

Comment: Or that it's going to become not so relaxing in the near future. *"Right now, it is relaxing to sit here under the sun and chat with you, but it won't be once that storm reaches the shore"*

Answer (score -1):

Sentences B are both correct. And identical in meaning.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Why are you going to sit there?" though.

Isn't the listener already sitting down in the sun chatting with you?